# git push heroku master gets stuck

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-cli

Git push heroku master gets stuck at

```
Enumerating objects: 1468, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1468/1468), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1142/1142), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1468/1468), 20.99 MiB | 44.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 1468 (delta 637), reused 993 (delta 275)
```

What do I do?

Comment: How long did you wait for it to finish?

Comment: I waited for an hour.

Comment: That sucks. How large is the repo? Did you add large files?

Comment: When `git push` finishes sending files to a heroku installation, heroku itself takes over: it will compile the files and do various checking and so on. That seems to be what's gotten stuck. It's not possible to say why: you need to ask whoever runs this particular heroku server.